# Java Thread processing with walkFileTree

Tags: java

I am new to java thread process, i found a sample code which i had some interest to know how their code flow,so i can put it into my code. This is my [reference](https://github.com/syncany/syncany/blob/59cf87c72de4322c737f0073ce8a7ddd992fd898/syncany-lib/src/main/java/org/syncany/operations/watch/RecursiveWatcher.java). I will register all the new created folder in main directory and sub directory with the WatchService using the `Files.walkFileTree()` 
 This is my sample folder structure

```
Root : C:/REST API/source/
sub directory : /source/abc/
```

First, i will register my root directory with the WatchService, and created `folder abc`. But i can't fully understand the flow of my compile debugging message when i try to conduct the testing like what i had describe before 
 Here is my compiler message

```
Register path for Watcher Service
The Main Path is :C:\REST API\source
The sub path is :C:\REST API\source
In RegisterDIR method () path valueC:\REST API\source
Register path for Watcher Service
The Main Path is :C:\REST API\source
The sub path is :C:\REST API\source
In RegisterDIR method () path valueC:\REST API\source
The Main Path is :C:\REST API\source
The sub path is :C:\REST API\source\New folder
In RegisterDIR method () path valueC:\REST API\source\New folder
Register path for Watcher Service
The Main Path is :C:\REST API\source
The sub path is :C:\REST API\source
In RegisterDIR method () path valueC:\REST API\source
The Main Path is :C:\REST API\source
The sub path is :C:\REST API\source\abc
In RegisterDIR method () path valueC:\REST API\source\abc
```

This is my sample code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public  class AbsolutePath<WatchListener>
{
    static Path mainPath;
    static WatchService svc;
    Thread watch;
    static Map <WatchKey , Path> keyMap;
    WatchKey wk;
    Timer timer;
    WatchListener lin;


    public static void main(String [] args ) throws IOException
    {

        mainPath = Paths.get("C:/REST API/source/");

        svc =  FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        keyMap = new HashMap<>();

        AbsolutePath ab = new AbsolutePath();

        ab.start();
    }

    private void start() throws IOException
    {

        watch = new Thread(new Runnable()
              {
                 public void run()
                 {
                    if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
                    {

                        walkTreeAndSetWatches();
                        while(true)
                        {
                            try 
                            {

                                wk = svc.take();

                                wk.pollEvents();

                                wk.reset();

                                newRegister();

                            } 
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }

              });

      watch.start();
    }
    private synchronized void walkTreeAndSetWatches()
    {
        System.out.println("Register path for Watcher Service");
        try
        {
            Files.walkFileTree(mainPath, new FileVisitor<Path>()
            {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attr) throws IOException 
                {
                     System.out.println("The Main Path is :"+mainPath);
                     System.out.println("The sub path is :"+path);
                    if(attr.isDirectory())
                    {

                         registerDIR(path);
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }



                @Override
                public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException 
                {

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
                {

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException 
                {

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }


            });
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void registerDIR(Path path) 
    {
        try 
        {
             System.out.println("In RegisterDIR method () path value"+path);
             keyMap.put(path.register(svc, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE),path);

        }

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

     private synchronized void newRegister() 
    {
      timer = new Timer();

      timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
              {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {

                    walkTreeAndSetWatches();


                }


              },3000);
    }

}
```

Can somebody help me understand why my code flow become like that, is it because the thread handle having some problem ? In my reference link, how they handle their event if there's folder/file created in the monitored directory because i can't found how it's handling this type of event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in your while loop you call newRegister() which in turn walks from the mainPath which is static.
Some suggestions:

- refactor the code in order to have no static left,
- this is a recursive algorithm, thus you need to pass the new paths to the new walker when registering a new path.

Additional question: what didn't you like in the original code that made you rewrite it? :) (another way of putting it: what kind of functionality did you want to add/remove?)

Comment: thanks for your comment , i can't find how they register the main path, so i modify a bit to fix it up. What i want to achieve the source code that i find is i will monitoring the main directory and sub directory as well which might contain new created folder. After that retrieve the folder path or file path.

Comment: What you describe is exactly what the github code you reference in your post is doing. Still don't understand what you want more/less. :)

Comment: I am doing a folder structure monitoring for any file/folder created and retrieve the correct path for the file/folder. I tested many way and fail to retrieve the correct path until i found an example on github which i like to try out their example for understand their code flow. See is it have second option for me to explore or not